# Define a relation ∼ on Z as x ∼ y if and only if |x− y| ≤ 1. Say whether ∼ is reflexive. Is it symmetric? Transitive?

Tags: solution-verification, relations

Just checking to see if I'm doing this right.

$|x-x| = 0 \le 1$ and similarly for y, so this is reflexive.

If $x,y \in Z$ then $|x - y | \le 1$ so $x\le 1+y$ and $y \ge x-1$

$|x- (x-1)| \le 1 \Rightarrow |-1|\le 1$. And for y: $|(1+y)-y|\le 1 \Rightarrow |1|\le1.$ So this is symmetric.

I'm a little stuck on proving transative. This is what I think the start looks like.

If $x,y,z \in Z$ for $|x-y|\le1$ and $|y-z|\le1$ then $y\ge x-1$ and $y\le 1+z$.

Comment: "I'm a little stuck on proving transative."  It's fairly common to get stuck while trying to prove something that isn't true.  Did you consider that just because they asked you if it was transitive that that doesn't mean it is?  Did it occur to you that maybe they want you to show it *isn't* transitive?

Comment: Consider what it *means*  $|x-y| \le 1$ means that $x$ and $y$ are within a distance of $1$ of each other.  Does it follow that if $x$ and $y$ are withing one of each other, and $y$ and $z$ are withing $1$ of each other, would that mean $x$ and $z$ are within one of each other.  Consider San Francisco is close to Sacramento, and Sacramento is close to Truckee, and Truckee is close to Reno, and .... Princeton is close to Trenton, and Trenton is close to New York.    Does that mean San Francisco is close to New York?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right that it is symmetric but I would simplify the proof even further by noting that $\lvert x-y\rvert = \lvert -(y-x) \rvert = \lvert y-x\rvert$.

As for transitivity, your relation is actually not transitive. Consider a simple counterexample of $x=2,y=3,z=4$. Clearly $\lvert 2-3\rvert \leq 1$ and $\lvert 3-4\rvert \leq 1$, but $\lvert 2-4\rvert = 2>1$, so it's not transitive.

Answer (score 1):

Your implications aren't strong enough.  $|x-y| \le 1$ does mean $y \ge x-1$ but it *also* means $x \ge y -1$ (you can't have $y=10,000$ and $x - 2$ even though $10,000 \ge 2-1$).

But you are well on your way....

If $|x-y | \le 1$ then $-1 \le x-y \le 1$ and if $|y-z| \le 1$ then  $-1 \le y -z \le 1$.  If we add those together we ge $-2 \le x - z \le 2$ and we can't seem to get any stronger.  And that gives us a germ of an idea for a counter example.

Suppose we had a case where $x-y < 1$. and $y-z < 1$ so $x-y + y-z = x-z < 2$ but what if we have $1< x-z < 2$.  Is that possible?

Then answer is .... sure, why not?

Let $x - y = \frac 34$ and $y- z = \frac 34$ so $x-z = 1\frac 12$.  We can easily to that, can't we?

$y -z = \frac 34$ so $y = z + \frac 34$ and $x-y =\frac 34$ so $x -(z+\frac 34) = \frac 34$ so $x = z + 1\frac 12$.  Just let $z = 0, y = \frac 34, z =1\frac 12$.

Counter example. Done.

.....

Oh,... I didn't see that the relation was on $\mathbb Z$ and not $\mathbb R$.  Well, no matter the idea is the same.  I only to $x-y = \frac 34$ to show there was some "leeway".  We could use $z=0;y=1; x=2$ just as easily.

......

But if $x,y \in \mathbb Z$ then $x-y\in \mathbb Z$ so $|x-y| \le 1$ means $x-y = -1,0,1$ which means in turn $x = \begin{cases}y-1\\y\\y+1\end{cases}$.

Viewing it *that* way we can note that

It is reflexive as $x =\begin{cases}\color{red}{x-1}\\\color{blue}x\\\color{red}{x+1}\end{cases}$.

And it is symmetric an $x=\begin{cases}\color{green}{y-1}\\\color{blue}{y}\\\color{orange}{y+1}\end{cases}$ would imply

$\begin{cases}\color{green}{y-1}\\\color{blue}{y}\\\color{orange}{y+1}\end{cases} = x$ which implies

$\begin{cases}\color{green}{y}\\\color{blue}{y}\\\color{orange}{y}\end{cases} =\begin{cases}x+1\\x\\x-1\end{cases} $ or

$y = \begin{cases}\color{green}{x+1}\\\color{blue}{x}\\\color{orange}{x-1}\end{cases}$

But it's not transitive as

$x = \begin{cases}y-1\\y \\y+1\end{cases}$ and $y = \begin{cases}z-1\\z\\z+1\end{cases}$ would imply

$x =\begin{cases}\begin{cases}z-2\\z-1\\z\end{cases}\\\begin{cases}z-1\\z\\z+1\end{cases}\\\begin{cases}z\\z+1\\z+2\end{cases}\end{cases}=\begin{cases}z-2\\z-1\\z\\z+1\\z+2\end{cases}$

Comment: Your logic is flawless but the relation was on $\mathbb{Z}$ so the counterexample doesn't fully fit.

Comment: Oops.  Didn't see that. but replace $x-z=\frac 34 < 1$ with $x-z = 1$ and it would work.  But wait.... if the relationship is on $\mathbb Z$ then the relationship is nothing more or less than $x = \begin{cases}y-1\\y\\y+1\end{cases}$.

Comment: Yes, you're essentially testing for $x$ being a successor of $y$, or vice versa (if $x\neq y$, that is)

Comment: My point is that's restrictive in such a way we can stest everything directly.

Comment: I understand. I upvoted your answer for the effort, hopefully the OP has another look at it :)